# What is the objective in Minecraft Classic?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I heard a lot of voices about MineCraft so I decided to visit its site. I found two versions there, MineCraft Alpha and MineCraft Classic.

I tried to play MineCraft Classic, but I didn't really understand what the purpose/objective of the game is, and I haven't found very much information on the site.

Could you please explain it to me?

Comment: +1 I was actually going to ask this exact question a couple days ago but I forgot to.

Comment: It may help to know that Minecraft Classic is also referred to as "Creative Mode".

Answer (score 45, accepted):

None. Dig around, build around, enjoy the work that has gone into the map generator, make awesome stuff and [share it on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c74D7kQywBY).

Comment: I tend to think of it as multiplayer online legos!

Comment: @Aeo I thought that was Blockland

Answer (score 14):

Minecraft Classic is the version where you simply build and let your imagination run wild. Minecraft Alpha is a more mature version where you mine, craft, build, and beat the crap out of zombies.

Comment: And now beta! So consider updating your answer.

Comment: @JoethePerson And now official!

Answer (score 7):

Minecraft is basically a huge sandbox of awesomeness, where you can do whatever you want!

Search for some youtube vids of things like "minecraft roller coaster" or "minecraft TNT."
Those vids will give you an idea of what some people do with it.... Although I am not sure what features are available in classic, because I spend most of time in Alpha.

Comment: Question is about classic version as stated, not alpha